# cesium.camera.flyTo can't be called twice inside a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, cesium

Is `cesium.camera.flyTo()` function a deferred javascript function? I mean this function is executed only after `<script>` is parsed. So what if I have to call `cesium.camera.flyTo()` more than once inside my `<script>` tag? The second call overrides the first call. Is there any better to get flights to multiple destinations in one go - like a loop of `flyTo's` or something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess one way to do that is using a `setTimeout` function. Placing the second call to `flyTo()` inside `setTimeout` would delay its execution by certain seconds and we can see the flight to second destination